# How can I specify a minimum length for my graph's edges?

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning, luatex, graphs

I've just started to use the (new?) `graphdrawing` library (see section 27 of the TikZ & PGF 3.0.0). It's awesome!

However, I can't seem to effect a minimum length for my graph's edges. That's problematic, because two connected nodes may overlap if the text they contain is too long, to the point where the connecting edge gets completely hidden; see below for an example.

I've tried to use the `node sep` key, but it doesn't seem to have any effect on edge length. What should I do for edges to have at least a length of, say, `1cm`?

[image]

```
% compile with LuaLaTeX
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{
  graphs,
  graphdrawing,
}

\tikzset{
  graphs/every graph/.style={nodes={draw}},
}

\begin{document}
\section*{Fine}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\graph{
  A -- B
};
\end{tikzpicture}

\section*{Too crammed}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\graph[
  node sep=1cm, % no effect
]{
  Cram -- med 
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: There are many options here, but for your particular case you could use `grow right=1cm` or `grow right sep=1cm`. See S19.9 of the [`pgfmanual`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/pgf) for complete documentation of the placement options.

Comment: @PaulGessler Yes, thanks. `grow right sep` is the key I was looking for. I'm still a noob when it comes to `\graph`. Post an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: Jubobs, totally up to you. It did take me a while to find the right spot in the manual, so it may come up with others in the future.

Comment: @PaulGessler There you go `:)` Thanks again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many, many options for the placement of graph nodes. These are covered in-depth in Section 19.9 of the current (v3.0) [`pgfmanual`](http://www.texdoc.net/pkg/pgf).

I assume your actual use case is more complex than this, so it's worth examining the options to choose the best one for your situation. But for this simple example, `grow right sep=1cm` should show the behavior you expected from the non-working `node sep` key.

**Code:**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{
  graphs,
  graphdrawing,
}

\tikzset{
  graphs/every graph/.style={nodes={draw}},
}

\begin{document}
\section*{Fine}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\graph{
  A -- B
};
\end{tikzpicture}

\section*{Too crammed}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\graph[
  grow right sep=1cm, % no effect
]{
  Cram -- med 
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Output:**

[image]